# Upon running this script, I get no feedback - bug searching

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, encoding

I've been working on a website, and upon my latest edit, adding password encryption, it no longer works. When I enter my username and correct password, it says the "Logged In Successfully" message. I'm not sure what is stopping it from continuing. If you see **anything**, question related or unrelated in the code, please tell me and I'd really appreciate it. I'm kind of novice to JS, so formatting issues may be the reason. Thank you so much!

By the way, the username is "ls120cbaJp" and password is "a295e42!@slopEGame!$"

```js
    const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
    const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
    const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");
    let encodedPassword = ("YTI5NWU0MiFAc2xvcEVHYW1lISQ=");
    let decodedPassword = window.atob(encodedPassword);
    
    loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       
       e.preventDefault();
       
       const username = loginForm.username.value;
       
       const password = loginForm.password.value;
       
       if (username === "ls120cbaJp" && password === decodedPasword) {
          
          alert("You have successfully logged in.");
          
          document.cookie = "login=True";
          
          let loginTrue = getCookie("login");
          
          if (loginTrue === "True") {
             window.location.replace("https://datlickk421503912fo3e35fjdgket353kjj3l.github.io/Ko3h2hlrkjdhflkj3hklgrjfKo3h2hlrkjdhflkj3hklgrjfKo3h2hlrkjdhflkj3hklgrjfKo3h2hlrkjdhflkj3hklgrjf/unity.html");
             //figure out how to delete the cookie here so you can't access again (security)
          } else {
             alert("No brute forcing :/");
          }
          
       } else {
          loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
       }
    })
```

Comment: Should be `window.atob(encodedPassword)` not `btoa`, also, never store passwords like `a295e42!@slopEGame!$` in plain text. `atob` and `btoa` are no security at all.

Comment: It's not for a commercial thing, it's just to show friends. How would you go about using a password encryption with more security?